# Devolver un valor en Swift

Tags: funciones, swift

No tengo demasiado conocimiento en Swift, así que probablemente esté cometiendo un error básico, pero me está volviendo loco lo siguiente:

Con una función me conecto a una API, que me devuelve un valor entero, y quiero devolverlo, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
func obtBultos(cod_conductor: Int) -> Int{
        
        var total: Int = 0

        NetworkingProvider.shared.getBultosConductor(empresagrupo: (user?.empresagrupo)!, cod_conductor: cod_conductor) { (pedid) in
               
               for bult in pedid{

                   if (cod_conductor == bult.cod_conductor){
                       self.bultoConductor = Int(bult.bultos!) ?? 0
                       total += self.bultoConductor
                   }
               }
               
                print("total 1: \(total)")  // Devuelve 100. Bien
            
           } failure: { (error) in
               print(error.debugDescription)
               return
           }
        
        print("total 2: \(total)")  // Devuelve 0. Mal, debería devolver 100.
        
        return total
    
    }
```

Es decir, le paso un código a la función, me suma todos los bultos y me retorna un total. Hasta ahí bien, sin problema. Pero el return, sólo me retorna 0.

Lo que pretende es que cuando llame a esta función por ejemplo:

> val cantidad = obtBultos(10)

me traiga el valor. Pero tal y como lo tengo, sólo me trae 0.

He intentado poner el valor total como variante global (al inicio de la clase), pero esa tampoco parece ser la explicación.

¿Alguna indicación? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona diferente cuando quieres devolver un valor de una llamada asíncrona de una Api; se utiliza `completion handler`, que es parte de los closures que indican que una tarea se finalizó o completó.

Modificando tu código:

1. Agregamos el parámetro `completion handler`:

   ```
   func obtBultos(cod_conductor: Int, completion: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)) {
   ```
2. Finalizada la llamada a la Api, necesitamos devolver el valor e indicamos que la tarea se a completado:

   ```
   completion("El valor a enviar")
   ```

Nota. Se debe devolver con el mismo nombre declarado en el parámetro, en este caso "completion".

El código completo:

```
func obtBultos(cod_conductor: Int, completion: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)) {
    var total: Int = 0

    NetworkingProvider.shared.getBultosConductor(empresagrupo: (user?.empresagrupo)!, cod_conductor: cod_conductor) { (pedid) in
           
           for bult in pedid{

               if (cod_conductor == bult.cod_conductor){
                   self.bultoConductor = Int(bult.bultos!) ?? 0
                   total += self.bultoConductor
               }
           }
           
            completion(total)//Completion handler
        
       } failure: { (error) in
           print(error.debugDescription)
           return
       }
}
```

Para obtener el valor llamamos a la función y la respuesta la añadimos a la variable:

```
var cantidad = 0

obtBultos(cod_conductor: 10) { total in
    cantidad = total//Se asigna el valor de a respuesta en la variable
    print(cantidad)//Se imprime
    //puedes hacer llamados a otras funciones desde aquí si lo necesitas.
    func1(cantidad)
}
```

Comment: Excelente explicación! Efectivamente era eso. Ahora funciona perfectamente. Mil gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

@Mimmetico con esta explicación también puedes resolver tu pregunta:
[Leer variable fuera de un bloque en Swift](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571344/leer-variable-fuera-de-un-bloque-en-swift/572459?noredirect=1#comment1013871_572459)

Un saludo.