# Leer variable fuera de un bloque en Swift

Tags: swift

tengo el siguiente problema con Swift:

Me gustaría acceder a la variable "total", que me viene después de haber llamado a la función "getPackagesDriver()". Hasta ahí bien, desde dentro del bloque me funciona bien.

El primer print me lee bien la variable; El segundo, no lee nada

El problema es que luego necesito rescatarla desde fuera (para añadirla a un Dictionary), pero eso ya no me deja hacerlo, lo cual me resulta un poco confuso.

Este es el código:

```
func getDrivers(){
        
        NetworkingProvider.shared.getDrivers() { (drivers) in
            
            for driver in drivers{
                
                self.getPackagesDriver(code: driver.code!){ total in
                    
                    self.result = total // Global variable
           
                    print("Result1 \(self.result)")  // This works OK. Return a number
                }
                
                print("Result: \(self.result)")  // This doesn't work. Return 0
                
                self.driversDictionary[driver.code!] = "\(self.result)"
            }
            
            for(key,value) in self.driversDictionary{
                
                self.name.append("\(key) - \(value)")
            }
            }
```

He intentado crear una variable global (declarada al inicio de la clase) llamada result y asignarle total a result, pero eso no funciona.

También he intentado poner el driverDictionary dentro del bloque getPackagesDriver... pero eso tampoco hace nada.

Creo que tiene que ver con que sea asíncrona, que no lee en el orden que está escrito, pero no sé cómo poder solucionar este problema, la verdad.

¿Alguna orientación? Gracias!

Comment: Por qué no llenas el diccionario dentro del closure `self.getPackagesDriver`?

Comment: Eso intenté, pero por algún motivo (seguramente mi desconocimiento), luego no puedo acceder al diccionario. Por ejemplo al intentar recorrerlo con el for(key,value... no me devuelve valores. Es como si todo lo que estuviera dentro de ese closure no fuera accesible desde fuera. Un poco confuso, la verdad.

Answer (score 1):

Mimmetico, como no tengo todo el código voy a dar por hecho un par de cosas:

1. Tu método getDrivers es asíncrono
2. driversDictionary es un diccionario de tipo [Int:String]

Tal y como te decía @Bicho, deberías rellenar el diccionario dentro del closure, no es que no te lo rellene, el for(key, value) no te imprime los valores rellenados porque estos, muy posiblemente, no han sido aún rellenados.

Te paso un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo, mediante un escaping closure. Es muy posible que tengas que adaptar código, ten en cuenta que no tengo el contexto, no conozco el tipado de tus propiedades, etc...

```
func getDrivers(callback: @escaping _ drivers: ([Int:String]) -> ()) {
        
    NetworkingProvider.shared.getDrivers() { (drivers) in
        
        var driversDictionary = [Int:String]()

        for driver in drivers {

            self.getPackagesDriver(code: driver.code!){ total in                
                driversDictionary[driver.code!] = "\(total)"
            }            
        }

        callback(driversDictionary)
        

    }
}

// Uso de la función: 
self.getDrivers() { (drivers) in

    for(key,value) in drivers {
        
        self.name.append("\(key) - \(value)")
    }
}
```

Espero que, al menos, puedas reutilizar la idea. Si quieres, te lo puedo montar con Async / Await en vez de closures, si te sientes más cómodo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, Jose Manuel. Creo que lo tengo más claro con tu explicación. Sólo una duda más, cómo llamarías a la función getDrivers() ? es decir, qué parámetros habría que pasarle? Muchas gracias por tu explicación!!

Comment: Buenas Mimético, solo has de pasarle el comportamiento que quieres que tenga la función al llamar a su parámetro "callback". Si no te sientes cómodo con el concepto de closure necesitarías revisar la documentación oficial al respecto: 

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

En resumen, callback es el único parámetro que has de pasarle a getDrivers(), callback es una variable que contiene una función de tipo ([Int:String]) -> void, una función anónima. Es muy difícil de entender hasta que no conozcas los closures en Swift. ¡Ánimo!